# Apple Search Ads API Ad Group Bid

Tags: json, ads-api, apple-search-ads

I'm trying to update ad group bids for a campaign.

Sending this data:

```
{"id": 12345, "campaignId": 6789, "name": "campaign", "defaultCPCBid": 
{"amount": "0.58", "currency": "USD"}}
```

Getting this response:

```
{"data":null,"pagination":null,"error":{"errors": 
[{"messageCode":"INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE","message":"Invalid 
field","field":"id"}, 
{"messageCode":"INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE","message":"Invalid 
field","field":"campaignId"}, 
{"messageCode":"INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE","message":"Invalid 
field","field":"defaultCPCBid"}]}}
```

Do you know what's the issue?

Note the path's and ids have been changed for confidentiality reasons.

Here's Everything Below:

Data Being Sent:

```
{"id": 12345, "campaignId": 6789, "name": "campaign", "defaultCPCBid": 
{"amount": "0.58", "currency": "USD"}}

CURL Command being sent to apple:
curl --verbose \
 -X PUT \
 -d @put.json \
 -H "Authorization: orgId=123456" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --cert '/home/field1/field2/Certificates/name.pem' \
 --key  '/home/path1/path2/Certificates/name.key' \
 --pass deletedText \
 'https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v1/campaigns/123456/adgroups/789
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Got the same problem ):

Comment: Still no luck, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Try sending only this data instead: ```{"defaultCPCBid": 
{"amount": "0.58", "currency": "USD"}}```

You don't need to send the rest of it (and can't) because it is already included in the url you send it too. Maybe after that it will stop rejecting defaultCPCBid?

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the apple search ads api reference:
https://searchads.apple.com/v/advanced/help/b/docs/pdf/management-api.pdf

It appears that the issue is that those fields are not updatable.
If you look for "Adgroup Fields" under "Adgroup object" in the api reference linked above you will find a table with a column of properties for each field, only certain fields have an "updateable" property (eg. name, status etc.).
I imagine the only way to change the other fields is to create a new Adgroup and delete the old one.

Hope this helps someone.